# Canonical Livepatch internal error

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I've started seeing a livepatch warning in my system tray.

[image: System tray icons.]

Clicking it takes me the the livepatch client where I see this error message:

[image: Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues for further information.]

Despite the URL, there isn't a #CommonIssues section on the page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues

Any ideas how I can fix this?

*Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

4.15.0-34-generic*

Comment: Run `sudo apt install gtk3-nocsd` and then `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`. Also, `canonical-livepatch refresh` require sudo privileges

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Note:** Some people have found simply running `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh` solves the problem. Try that first and then, if the problem persists, follow the steps below.

---

This [forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420465) describes the same issue and says the solution is to use a new livepatch token:

1. disable the livepatch service `sudo canonical-livepatch disable`
2. get a new token from https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/
3. enable the service with your new token `sudo canonical-livepatch enable <your token>`
4. restart livepatch service

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
   ```

Comment: I started getting this after cloning to a new SSD.  Getting a new token fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me.

Comment: A simple `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh` works for me just fine. I think this is an easier way to solve the problem, which makes sense to try before disabling the entire service.

Answer (score 22):

In terminal i just fire this command and it worked, try this

```
sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
```

In Detail you can read here

1. [Canonical Livepatch informs about internal error - what to do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150844/canonical-livepatch-informs-about-internal-error-what-to-do)
2. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420465

Comment: I started to receive error after manual update and restart of computer (restart was required even before livepatch was activated on the machine). This one helped. Thx,

Comment: Thanks, `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh` works fine for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Very simple and useful.

Comment: My kernel was updated to a newer version as proposed by Canonical. That was the reason of the exclamation mark for me.
"nothing to apply
kernel:  (unsupported)
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet"

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other methods, but had to remove the lock file for some reason and restart the service.

`s=snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service; sudo rm /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_15_0_71_78_generic_95_95.4 && sudo systemctl restart && sudo systemctl status`

Answer (score -1):

1. head to the Livepatch page and create an account. You can license up to 3 servers for free, so there is no cost unless you plan to mass deploy Livepatch. https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch
2. Once you've created an account it's as simple as running the following commands:

   ```
   sudo snap install canonical-livepatch  
   sudo canonical-livepatch enable $your_token
   ```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! According to the question, OP had livepatch set up already but got a problem with it. Your answer is not even trying to solve this problem.

Comment: When you register the 4th machine using token from the free account version, the first machine will stop updating which is a plausible explanation of the error encountered. It definitely solved my problem.