# Canonical Livepatch informs about internal error - what to do?

Tags: 18.04, canonical-livepatch

In my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop I have now, after today's software updates last kernels 4.15.0-50-generic and 4.15.0-51-generic and Canonical Livepatch installed and enabled today.

Problem: I have red exclamation mark on Livepatch icon on right upper corner of the screen and I get following info from Livepatch Settings: 1.) ’’Livepatch is on’’ and 2.) ’’Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#Commonissues for further information.’’ Does this mean that Livepatch is working OK or not in this desktop ? Should I do something ?

///Background: Until today I had similar problem (and information as above) in my other desktop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But after today's software update (among others installed latest kernel 4.15.0-51-generic and removed old kernel -48) the red exclamation mark on icon changed automatically to green V-mark and Livepatch Settings informs: 1.) ’’Livepatch is on’’ and 2.) ’’Last check for updates 13.6.2019 16:28 (48 minutes ago)''. So this it looks like all is OK.///

---

```
 Adasiko hi,
```

1.) At first I made the following with the desktop in question: I re-installed Livepatch, launched it and acquired machine token. After this the Livepatch icon appeared with the green V-mark.

2.) After this I made as you asked and below are the results from terminal.

3.) After this I re-booted the desktop and the results were same as earlier yesterday, i.e.. the re-boot with mouse only failed (only start from power-on switch succeeded), Livepatch icon appeared with RED exclamation mark and Livepatch Setting inform about ''internal error'' as earlier. Yesterday after these same results I uninstalled Livepatch (as you see from my earlier comment). Now I did the same thing.

Brgds

Terminal:

Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-26 17:11:19 EET, end at Sun 2019-06-16 11:48:15 EEST. --

```
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-liveepatchd.
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: starting client daemon version 9.3.0
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: starting svc "mitigation loop"
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: service "mitigation loop" started
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: starting svc "socket servers"
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: service "socket servers" started
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: starting svc "refresh loop"
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: service "refresh loop" started
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: client daemon started
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: Client.Check
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: error in livepatch check state: needs-check
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: No payload available.
kesä 16 11:35:12 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: during refresh: cannot check: No machine-token. Please run 'canonical-livepatc
kesä 16 11:35:26 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: error in livepatch check state: needs-check
kesä 16 11:43:26 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: error in livepatch check state: needs-check
kesä 16 11:47:54 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: Client.Check
kesä 16 11:47:54 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: error in livepatch check state: needs-check
kesä 16 11:47:54 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: Checking with livepatch service.
kesä 16 11:47:56 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: updating last-check
kesä 16 11:47:56 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: touched last check
kesä 16 11:47:56 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: No updates available at this time.
kesä 16 11:47:56 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: No payload available.
kesä 16 11:47:56 HP-EliteBook-8530p canonical-livepatch[2990]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
```

Comment: Check logs 
`journalctl --since today -u snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service`

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me

```
sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
```

for more go to [Thread: Canonical internal error](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420465)

Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice. I tried it and the problem disappeared in my 2nd desktop. But after rebooting the same problem ('internal error') was back. I tested 3 times. In my 1st desktop this problem disappeared after software update to kernel 4.15.0-51 and has not repeated / retuRned since that (i.e. all is OK).

Comment: Additional info: simple rebooting of the desktop with problematic Livepatch ('internal error') failed; I had to make rebooting with full energy off  with the mouse / energy on with the power switch. This rebooting problem disappeared when I uninstalled Livepatch and now simple rebooting (with the mouse) works again correctly.

Comment: This fixes it for me, but I have to do it every time I log in.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, instead it said: "checking for patches
nothing to apply
kernel: 4.15.0-55.60-generic
patch state: ✗ patches are no longer available for this version of the kernel, please upgrade
patch version: 59.1"

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://ubuntu.com/livepatch
Subscribe to Livepatch
Free for 3 machines. 
All you need is an Ubuntu One account.
Get yours now.

Get your livepatch token.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch disable
sudo canonical-livepatch enable  --Copy and paste your token here--
```

Comment: Unfortunately after rebooting the problem reappears. I guess we have to wait for a fix!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo canonical-livepatch disable
```

Head over to https://ubuntu.com/livepatch and sighn up for "Free for personal use".

Use the assigned token to re-enable the service:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable <your_token_here>
```

Reboot!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience if there is working internet connection on your PC and your router, when powering on the system there is no issues with Canonical Livepatch. If your PC internet connection is OFF when booting you will get an error. The problem is I believe that Canonical does not do refresh its connection to servers until they are connected but only on boot. Like this user is encouraged to keep his connection ON on boot to avoid error or to do "sudo canonical-livepatch refresh" every time error occurred.

Comment: @ mao Thank you for your reply. My PC's are always online when booting. I think some fix was made since no problems with updated kernels 5.3.0-xyz. At present in case if Livepatch is installed correctly and enabled with Canonical Livepatch token,  running command 'sudo canonical-livepatch refresh' solves the problem.

Comment: it happens also when changing wifi during reboot like when you shut down at one place with wifi and open it in another place with another wifi

Answer (score 0):

Run this as suggested on the [Ubuntu Advantage Dashboard](https://ubuntu.com/advantage):

```
sudo ua attach <subscription>
```

When you click on the *Sign in* option in Livepatch settings, it will automatically redirect to the same and ask you to login/signup.