# Livepatch freezing ubuntu

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with livepatch.

My computer often freezes for half an hour (or longer), at which point it seems swap and `snapd` are using all the cpu (quad-core) and ram (16 Gb).
When it starts responding again, there is a message saying that livepatch has finished.

I am not happy with this and would like to restrict the times livepatch is allowed to hijack my computer... for instance, could it not update while I sleep?

Only other option I see is to remove livepatch from my main computer (not ideal either).

Any thoughts?

OUTPUT of `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh`

Before refresh:

```
kernel: 4.15.0-50.54-generic
fully-patched: true
version: "58.1"
```

After refresh:

```
kernel: 4.15.0-50.54-generic
fully-patched: true
version: "58.1"
```

So it seems livepatch IS successful but just takes all my PC resources to do its thing?

Comment: If you shut down and restart your computer occasionally, it's hard to see the point of livepatch.

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh`. Check [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1142602/349837)

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Exactly, I do not regularly reboot my ubuntu PC. Perhaps once every 6+ weeks and only if I really have to.

Comment: @PabloA Thank you for that link, but it does not seem to directly impact the issue I describe.