# Persistent LivePatch internal error

Tags: canonical, canonical-livepatch

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. LivePatch informs me:

> Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to [Kernel/Livepatch - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues) for further information.

As per instructions I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142602/canonical-livepatch-internal-error), I've disabled and re-enabled LivePatch with a [fresh auth](https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/?user_type=ubuntu-user) from Canonical. Yet the issue persists, and the error message remains. Does anyone know what else might be causing this?

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1167348/972665

Comment: @blacksheep That was the first thing I tried--once that didn't work, I re-enabled with the new auth, and after that didn't work I posted the question.