# Can't attach canonical-livepatch with my token

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, canonical-livepatch, ubuntu-pro

I just successfully installed and configured an *Ubuntu Core 18 image for Intel Dawson Canyon and June Canyon NUC* by following this [official guide](https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc) to run (mainly) my Nextcloud instance.

The choice of Ubuntu Core for me is to spend the less time as possible on manual OPS action. And for years it has done a good job (*before this install, my server was on a raspi*).

After finishing the migration to this new server (*physical machine, an intel NUC*), I thought it would be cool to enable Livepatch.
I have an Ubuntu account where my Ubuntu member is well activated (50 machines possible, already 1 active only: my desktop), so my [Ubuntu Pro dashboard](https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard) looks like this:

[image: See attached image]

I have installed the `canonical-livepatch` snap, and tried to attach my server to my account (Note that my ubuntu core machine is already "linked" to my account to add my sudoer user+ssh key, during Ubuntu Core install step, not sure it counts):

```bash
$ sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose
Machine is not enabled. Please run 'sudo canonical-livepatch enable' with the token obtained from https://ubuntu.com/livepatch.
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable 
token not provided
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable HereIsMyToken
failed to register client: unauthorized
$ sudo canonical-livepatch attach HereIsMyToken
subcommand "attach" unknown
```

Officials guides mention commands line that are not on Ubuntu Core or just outdated (`sudo pro attach TheToken` , `sudo ua attach TheToken`, …), but the manual is explicit about the token after `enable`. It still fails. Am I doing it wrong?

```bash
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable  --help
canonical-livepatch enable - enable livepatching on the machine

USAGE:
   canonical-livepatch enable <token>

FLAGS:
--az (= "")
    The availability zone of the instance the livepatch client is being enabled on.
--cloud (= "")
    The public cloud name this livepatch client is being enabled on.
--region (= "")
    The region of the instance the livepatch client is being enabled on.
```

Here just a little check that my connection is OK (I did installed the snap a moment ago anyway.):

```bash
$ ping canonical.com
PING canonical.com(website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=8.74 ms
64 bytes from website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=8.72 ms
64 bytes from website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=8.68 ms
64 bytes from website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=8.71 ms
64 bytes from website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=8.76 ms
64 bytes from website-content-cache-1.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::26): icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=8.73 ms
^C
--- canonical.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.682/8.726/8.761/0.059 ms
```

Comment: Should i open a bug? (lp? found an empty repo on lp)  
Note that I have [issue to log in on askubuntu with lp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483716/cant-attach-canonical-livepatch-with-my-token), not sure there is a link between them, but just in case…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

It seems that I could attach my machine by using a totally other token, coming from a page i found in another [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142647/1726344).

The token that didn't work comes from this page:
https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard

The token that works comes from this page: https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/

Both page provided me a **different token**.

[The working token from auth.livepatch.canonical.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8imVk.png)

```bash
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable thisOtherTokenFromAuth.livepatch.canonical.com
Successfully enabled device. Using machine-token: thisOtherTokenFromAuth.livepatch.canonical.com
```

All guides will link to the ubuntu.com pro dashboard, not to the livepatch canonical auth, which contains a warning message that the pro dashboard should be used:

> The procedure for enabling Livepatch has been improved and using this
> page is no longer required. To enable Livepatch please follow the
> instructions at https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch.

*(with +1click you will be at your ubuntu.com pro dashboard)*

Note: My ubuntu pro dashboard still tell me there is only 1 device attached to my account (my desktop), using the other token, i can't track that my server is linked too.
[Count of 1 machine at https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCKqv.png)

In conclusion, I guess there is something to be fixed in the guides, or in the dashboard. There is a confusion for users like me. If any canonical people here, please take this in consideration <3